# Block direct url enter

Tags: urls

I want to block / disable direct url entering into address bar. Is it possible in wordpress? Actually I have created custom login, profile and other pages so don't want to allow user to go through wp-admin and I want to block all direct url entering.

Answer (score 3):

Preventing users from entering URLs manually in the address bar is not possible in WordPress, or from any site, for that matter. It can only be done via a browser plugin.

However, redirecting users or displaying a 404 page for a certain URL is easy to do and there are several WordPress plugins for blocking admin access. One example:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-admin-block/

Comment: Thanks for reply Scribu, but unfortunatly its not the solution what I am looking for but may be you are right. Its not possible to block direct url entering. Anyways Thanks a lot I have redirect all user to my custom login screen... Thanks again